# How do I point out whether the propositions are implying one another?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

1) It’s raining but the birds chirp.

2) If it’s not raining then the birds chirp.

3) It’s raining or the birds do not chirp.

For each pair of propositions, point out whether the second is implied by the first, and whether the first is implied by the second.

Steps I took:

First, I set each part of the first claim and set it equal to the variables $p,q$ as such:

$$p = raining, q= birds\quad chirp$$

Then, I wrote truth tables for each claim as such:

[image]

Now, I don't know how I am exactly supposed to go about figuring our whether each pair of propositions are implied by one another. I would like to be guided in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one statement implies a second statement if, whenever the first one is true, the second one is true also.

So, for instance, $p \wedge q$ implies both the other statements.

You can also make truth tables for $(p \wedge q) \implies (\lnot p \implies q)$,
and $(p \wedge q) \implies (p \vee \lnot q)$, and so on. If they are tautologies then the implications hold.

Comment: I don't understand how I'm supposed to check that. Is it just making a truth table for $p\wedge q\Rightarrow (\neg p\Rightarrow q)$ and the $5$ other claims?

Comment: ah! Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: Yes. You can also just look at the truth tables you already have and see when the $T$ entries in one are a subset of the $T$ entries in another.

Comment: The only ones that implied one another were $(p \wedge q) \implies (\lnot p \implies q)$ and $(p \wedge q) \implies (p \vee \lnot q)$. The other 4 were all $F$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R$ denote raining and $C$ denote chirping.

Assuming that the interpretation of 1) is $R \land C$, then it should
be clear that if 1) is true then both $R,C$ are true, hence 2), 3) are true. So
1) $\implies$ 2), 1) $\implies$ 3).

If 2) is true, then one possible assignment is $R$ true and $C $ false, hence
2) does not imply 1).

If 2) is true, then one possible assignment is $R$ false and $C $ true, hence
2) does not imply 3).

A similar analysis applies to 3).